# How to preventing inheritance in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

How to preventing inheritance in Objective-C?

I need to either prevent it, or issue a compiler warning referring to the projects documentation.

I came up with the following, which I am not sure if works in all scenarios.

main

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Child.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Child *c = [[Child alloc] init];
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Parent Class**

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Parent : NSObject

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Parent.h"

@implementation Parent

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    NSString *callingClass = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    if ([callingClass compare:@"Parent"] != NSOrderedSame) {
        [NSException raise:@"Disallowed Inheritance." format:@"%@ tried to inherit Parent.", callingClass];
    }
    return [super allocWithZone:zone];
}

@end
```

**Child Class**

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Parent.h"

@interface Child : Parent

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Child.h"

@implementation Child

@end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent inheritance? Is this some form of OCD?

Comment: @trojanfoe Undesired inheritance reduces maintainability. I have updated the question.

Comment: And how's that going?

Comment: `NSStringFromClass([self class])` should be `NSStringFromClass(self)` since it's a class method. You don't need the string comparison either, simply use `if (self != [Parent class])`. I'm not sure if there's any other way but this looks good to me.

Comment: preventing the inheritance, use the `@interface Child : NSObject` instead.

Comment: if he has the code that's fine. but he wants some sort of assert for this and I find it valid. UIKit does this with methods that need to call super or parameter asserts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the general approach looks good to me but why the string compare? Going after the class's name doesn't seem clean

here's a variant that does it comparing the `Class` objects:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject 
@end
@implementation A
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Class cls = [A class];
    Class childCls = [self class];

    if (childCls!=cls) {
        [NSException raise:@"Disallowed Inheritance." format:@"%@ tried to inherit %@.", NSStringFromClass(childCls), NSStringFromClass(cls)];
    }
    return [super allocWithZone:zone];
}
    @end

@interface B : A
@end
@implementation B
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        A *a = [[A alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@",a);
        B *b = [[B alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `NSStringFromClass()` in order to print the class names?

Comment: no [class description] prints the name -- at least it works right now

Comment: looking it up and modifying the answer as needed

Comment: guess I rely on an implementation detail here